# Concatanate two cell values in print

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a text file which contains an insert statement for SQL using a macro.

The bit I'm struggling on right now is that I need the values of A and B to concatanate into one line in the output file, but instead they go on to two separate lines.

I can't put all the data into one cell as when it prints it exceeds 255 characters and cuts off.

The bits I have that are the problem are -

```
Set rng_Data = Range("Output!Output")
```

Where `Output!` is the worksheet and `Output` is a named range of data.

Then further down -

```
For Each cell In rng_Data
    'Print the data string to the txt file
    Print #int_FreeFile01, Format(cell.Value)
Next
```

Ideally I thought this should be written like -

```
Set rng_Data = Range("Output!A1&B1:A116&B116")
```

But I just can't get this to work. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Set rng_Data = Sheets("Output!").Range(Define Range)
might be a good place to start.
Also, you should post your entire code to make it easier to assist.

Comment: I did try your suggestion - Set rng_Data = Sheets("Output!").Range("A1&B1:A116&B116") But I get a 'subscript out of range' error.

Comment: Are you looking for a string of data or to select the range?  Proper syntax on selecting a range would be: Set rng_Data = Sheets("Output!").Range(A1:B116)
Please clarify the range you are trying to grab.

Comment: Is your sheet name actually "Output!"?  Do you use that exclamation point in the actual name?  You only use exclamation points in formulas, not in VBA.  So perhaps you should be writing rng_Data = Sheets("Output").Range(A1:B116)

Comment: I want the range, I have 116 rows, but I want to concatenate the two cells for each row in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes you will always have 116 rows:

```
Sub PrintToNote()

Dim CurRow As Long
Dim CelCon As String

For CurRow = 1 To 116
    CelCon = Sheets("Output").Cells(CurRow, 1).Value & Sheets("Output").Cells(CurRow, 2).Value
    Print #int_FreeFile01, CelCon
    Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Just needs some work on the print command...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your range is A1:B116

```
Set rng_Data = Range(Sheets("Output").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Output").Cells(116, 2))

Open "C:\myfile.txt" For Output As #1

For Each cell In rng_Data
    'Print new line if the cell is in column 1
    If cell.Column = 1 Then Print #1, ""
    'Print the cell value without new line ending
    Print #1, cell.Value;

Next

Close #1
```